# Unzip Password Protected ZIP File And Send It's Content By Email Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, email, encryption

there!!
Here is my goal, I'm trying accomplish with Powershell script.
I have administrative user that need to be able extract csv file from password protected zip file and send this csv file by email.
Given directory has many zip files named by username (e.g. dana.zip) and protected with the same password (123456). The administrative user (who know the password for zip files) needs to run powershell script which asking for input desired user name and then do it's staff - extract file to the same directory and send it by email.
So far I find and adopt for above needs following powershell scripts.

Unzip Password protected file:

```
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input Desired User Name'
write-host ""
write-host " --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
write-host ""
write-host " Desired file will be extracted to W:\ADMINISTRATION folder " -foregroundcolor Cyan
write-host ""
write-host " --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
write-host ""
$zipFile = '"W:\ADMINISTRATION\$User.zip"'
$zipFilePassword = "123456"
$command = "&amp; $7ZipPath e -oW:\ADMINISTRATION -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile"
iex $command
```

This script doing it's job, but I'm trying to avoid usage of password as plain text in the script. Since this script will be run under same administrative user account I've tried to use encrypted password file in the script.

First, I've run following command to create encrypted password file:

```
"123456" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "W:\Admin\ZipPassword.txt"
```

Afterwards I've adopt my script to use encrypted password file:

```
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input Desired User Name'
write-host ""
write-host " --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
write-host ""
write-host " Desired file will be extracted to W:\\ADMINISTRATION folder " -foregroundcolor Cyan
write-host ""
write-host " --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
write-host ""
$zipFile = '"W:\ADMINISTRATION\$User.zip"'
$cred = Get-Content "W:\Admin\ZipPassword.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$zipFilePassword = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ($cred)
$command = "&amp; $7ZipPath e -oW:\ADMINISTRATION -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile"
iex $command
```

When running this script I'm getting following error:

[image: Powershell Error Message]

If it possible to make this script use encrypted password file it will me very beneficial...

The second script - sending extracted file by email.

First, I've created encrypted password file (in this script it 's working perfectly):

```
"myPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "W:\Admin\EmailPassword.txt"
```

And here is the script itself:

```
$User = "me.me@gmail.com"
$File = "W:\Admin\EmailPassword.txt"
$cred=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$EmailTo = "me.me@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "me.me@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Some text here"
$Body = "Some text here"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$filenameAndPath = "W:\ADMINISTRATION\dana.csv"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$Attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($cred.UserName, $cred.Password);
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
write-host "Mail Sent Successfully !!"  -foregroundcolor Green
```

This script working as expected... The only problem is that administrative user need edit it each time and put proper filename (dana.csv, david.csc... etc). Of course I can use user input method in this script as well, but I want to combine both scripts into the single one... So far I tried this one:

```
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$User = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input Desired User Name'
write-host ""
write-host " --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
write-host ""
write-host " Desired file will be extracted to W:\\ADMINISTRATION folder " -foregroundcolor Cyan
write-host ""
write-host " --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
write-host ""
$zipFile = '"W:\ADMINISTRATION\$User.zip"'
$zipFilePassword = "123456"
$command = "&amp; $7ZipPath e -oW:\ADMINISTRATION -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile"
iex $command

$User = "me.me@gmail.com"
$File = "W:\Admin\EmailPassword.txt"
$cred=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$EmailTo = "me.me@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "me.me@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Some text here"
$Body = "Some text here"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$filenameAndPath = "W:\ADMINISTRATION\$User.csv"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$Attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($cred.UserName, $cred.Password);
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
write-host "Mail Sent Successfully !!"  -foregroundcolor Green
```

But it's failed to attach file to email. I think I have problem here (wrong syntax):

```
$filenameAndPath = "W:\ADMINISTRATION\$User.csv"
```

So, if someone can help me to fix following issues, it will be much appreciated:

1. In the first portion of script, use encrypted password file instead of plain text
2. In the second portion, adopt user input from the first part of the script ($User) to be used as file name (for instance, if user input was "dana" , $User.csv will be equal to dana.csv)
3. Remove *.csv file after mail was sent.

Thank you in advance,

Igor.

Comment: You say: `Desired file will be extracted to W:\\ADMINISTRATION folder` in your user instructions, and then your code reads: `$zipFile = '"W:\ADMINISTRATION\$User.zip"'`  Are you missing a "\" in there?

Comment: No, it's just typo error... should be: W:\ADMINISTRATION...

Comment: I've figured out what was wrong with issue #2, - I've using same variable $User in first portion of script and in second... so second $User variable override already existing, firs one. That's why file wasn't attached to email. I've changed $User variable to $Username in firs portion of the script and now all good:

$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input Desired User Name' 

So, need help to fix issues 1 & 3...

Comment: You cannot completely avoid having a reversible password in your script while using an external command like `7z` unless it also supports encrypted passwords being passed to it.  `SecurePassword` is a Windows-specific construct.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed all the issues after "googling" them, So I can share my experience...

> 1. In the first portion of script, use encrypted password file instead of plain text

Like TheIncorrigible1 mentioned in his answer on my question:

> You cannot completely avoid having a reversible password in your
>   script while using an external command like 7z unless it also supports
>   encrypted passwords being passed to it. SecurePassword is a
>   Windows-specific construct.

It looks like 7zip not supporting Windows-specific encrypted password, so I need convert it back to plain text before using it.
I've found how to do it in those sites:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2009/09/10/powershell-one-liner-decrypt-securestring/#comment-6495 
and 
http://www.travisgan.com/2015/06/powershell-password-encryption.html

So this peace of code helped me out fixing encrypted password issue:

```
$Password = Get-Content 'W:\Administration\EncryptedPasswords\ZipPassword.txt'| ConvertTo-SecureString 
$Marshal = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
$Bstr = $Marshal::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)
$ZipPassword = $Marshal::PtrToStringAuto($Bstr)
$Marshal::ZeroFreeBSTR($Bstr)
```

> 2. In the second portion, adopt user input from the first part of the script ($User) to be used as file name (for instance, if user input
>      was "dana" , $User.csv will be equal to dana.csv)

This was my mistake,- I've used the same variable $User in the first and second portions of script, so $User variable from second portion of script override existing one... Therefore file wasn't attached to email.  After changing variable in the first portion of script, issue goes away:

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please Input Desired User Name'....
$zipFile = "W:\ADMINISTRATION\$UserName.zip"...
$filenameAndPath = "W:\ADMINISTRATION\$UserName.csv"
```

> 3. Remove *.csv file after mail was sent.
>      I've accomplished this goal using separate PowerShell script:

```
Get-ChildItem W:\Administration\*.csv | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | remove-item

write-host " ---------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan 
write-host "" 
write-host "     All Operations Completed Successfully !!"     -foregroundcolor Green                    
write-host ""
write-host " ---------------------------------------------- " -foregroundcolor DarkCyan
```